# launchd.plist runs every 10 seconds instead of just once

Tags: macos, usb, launchd

I have been setting up a `launchd.plist` XML that is run every time a specific USB device is mounted. I followed the instructions on the [xpc_events(3) man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/xpc_set_event_stream_handler.3.html) and it is running the application whenever the device is mounted.

The problem I'm having is that the application is run again and again every 10 seconds as long as the device is still mounted. How can I set it up so it only runs once when the device is inserted in the USB port?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myapp.agent</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAgent</string>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.matching</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.device-attach</key>
            <dict>
                <key>idVendor</key>
                <integer>2316</integer>
                <key>idProduct</key>
                <integer>4096</integer>
                <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
                <key>IOMatchLaunchStream</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>com.apple.notifyd.matching</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.interesting-notification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Notification</key>
                <string>com.apple.interesting-notification</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIUI your application must call xpc_set_event_stream_handler to remove the event from the queue. You might also have to add `<key>KeepAlive</key><false/>` to the .plist, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Incidentally, if you fail to set IOMatchLaunchStream to true, then xpc_set_event_stream_handler doesn't make any difference, and your app relaunches over and over as soon as you quit it.  Just a helpful tip.

Comment: per the `launchd.plist` man page, the default of `KeepAlive` is `false`

Comment: Found this amazing utility that will call xpc_set_event_stream_handler to remove the event from the queue, and then call your desired application. Allowed me to come up with a solution without compiling any code. Check out https://github.com/snosrap/xpc_set_event_stream_handler

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a [tutorial on this](https://github.com/himbeles/mac-device-connect-daemon) with detailed instructions and example files for triggering an arbitrary executable or shell script by the connection of an external device (usb/thunderbolt) to a Mac computer, without the respawning problem.

Like the authors approach, it relies on Apple's `IOKit` library for device detection and a daemon for running the desired executable. For the daemon to not be triggered repeatedly after connecting the device, a special stream handler (`xpc_set_event_stream_handler`) is used to "consume" the `com.apple.iokit.matching` event, as explained in the post by @ford and in his [github repo](https://github.com/snosrap/xpc_set_event_stream_handler).

In particular, the tutorial describes how to compile the xpc stream handler and how to reference it together with the executable in the daemon plist file and where to place all the relevant files with correct permissions.

For the files, please go [here](https://github.com/himbeles/mac-device-connect-daemon). For completeness, I have also pasted their content below.

## Run shell script or executable triggered by device detection on a mac

Here I use the example of spoofing the MAC address of an ethernet adapter when it is connected to the Mac. This can be generalized to arbitrary executables and devices.

### Put your shell script or executable into place

Adapt the shell script `spoof-mac.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig en12 ether 12:34:56:78:9A:BC
```

to your needs and
make it executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 spoof-mac.sh
```

Then move it into `/usr/local/bin`, or some other directory:

```
cp spoof-mac.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

### Building the stream handler

The stream handler `xpc_set_event_stream_handler.m`

```
//  Created by Ford Parsons on 10/23/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Ford Parsons. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <xpc/xpc.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        xpc_set_event_stream_handler("com.apple.iokit.matching", NULL, ^(xpc_object_t _Nonnull object) {
            const char *event = xpc_dictionary_get_string(object, XPC_EVENT_KEY_NAME);
            NSLog(@"%s", event);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        if(argc >= 2) {
            execv(argv[1], (char **)argv+1);
        }
    }
}
```

is universal (no need to adapt) and can be built on a mac command line (with xcode installed):

```
gcc -framework Foundation -o xpc_set_event_stream_handler xpc_set_event_stream_handler.m
```

Let's place it into `/usr/local/bin`, like the main executable for the daemon.

```
cp xpc_set_event_stream_handler /usr/local/bin/
```

### Setup the daemon

The plist file `com.spoofmac.plist` contains the properties of the daemon that will run the executable on device connect trigger.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/spoofmac.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/spoofmac.stdout</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.spoofmac.program</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/xpc_set_event_stream_handler</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/spoofmac.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.matching</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.apple.device-attach</key>
            <dict>
                <key>idVendor</key>
                <integer>32902</integer>
                <key>idProduct</key>
                <integer>5427</integer>
                <key>IOProviderClass</key>
                <string>IOPCIDevice</string>
                <key>IOMatchLaunchStream</key>
                <true/>
                <key>IOMatchStream</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It contains information for identifying the device you want to base your trigger on, like `idVendor`, `idProduct`, `IOProviderClass`. These can be figured out in the `System Information` App on your mac.

[image: Screenshot System Information]

Convert the hex identifiers to integers before inserting into the plist file (for example using `int(0x8086)` in python).

`IOProviderClass` should be either `IOPCIDevice` (Thunderbolt) or `IOUSBDevice` (USB).

The other relevant entry in the plist file is the location of `xpc_set_event_stream_handler` and the executable.

Other entries include the location of standard output (log) files and the executing user.

Since MAC spoofing requires root privileges, we put `com.spoofmac.plist` into `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```
cp com.spoofmac.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

not into a `LaunchAgents` folder. Launch agents ignore the `UserName` argument.

Insure that the owner of the file is `root`:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.spoofmac.plist
```

### Launch the daemon

Activate the daemon:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.spoofmac.plist
```

and you are good to go.

Unloading is done using `launchctl unload`.

---

## GUI App

I have wrapped the functionality of the Launch Daemon described above in a **more user-friendly Mac app, called ["Stecker"](https://stecker.himbeles.de)**. In addition to device attachment, the app can also detect device detachment.
It triggers the execution of selected Shortcuts from the macOS Shortcuts App.
The app is very lightweight and relies only on `IOKit` notifications.
In contrast to the launch approach, the direct use of the `IOKit` framework permits to filter for additional types of `com.apple.iokit.matching` events, such as device detachment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19476062)

Comment: I changed the post to include all of the external link content.

Comment: How do you debug when this does not work? I followed everything but just see entries in the error log `2022-03-22 16:40:35.217 xpc_set_event_stream_handler[65373:5653115] com.apple.device-attach`.  I'm guessing there's an issue with the filter or the script but not sure, I've tried both the product/vendor IDs for the USB hub and the device itself.  Also will this start at boot or do you need to load each time?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to use something like this:

```
#include <xpc/xpc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    asl_log(NULL, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG, "event_stream_handler: starting");

    xpc_set_event_stream_handler("com.apple.iokit.matching", dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(xpc_object_t event) {
        const char *name = xpc_dictionary_get_string(event, XPC_EVENT_KEY_NAME);
        uint64_t id = xpc_dictionary_get_uint64(event, "IOMatchLaunchServiceID");
        asl_log(NULL, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG, "event_stream_handler: received event: %s: %llu", name, id);

        execv(argv[1], argv + 1);
    });

    dispatch_main();

    return 0;
}
```

So a script which consumes the event and runs the script passed as an argument.

Comment: I think calling `execv` inside the `xpc_set_event_stream_handler` handler prevents the event from being consumed. Calling `execv` outside of the handler worked great. I posted my code [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895921/74530).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        xpc_set_event_stream_handler("com.apple.iokit.matching", NULL, ^(xpc_object_t _Nonnull object) {
            const char *event = xpc_dictionary_get_string(object, XPC_EVENT_KEY_NAME);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        if(argc >= 2) {
            execv(argv[1], (char **)argv+1);
        }
    }
}
```

[full source code here](https://github.com/snosrap/xpc_set_event_stream_handler)