# How to run an Applescript when a mouse is connected?

Tags: applescript, mouse

I have an Applescript that changes my mouse tracking speed that I want to run whenever I connect a mouse to my laptop. How do I do something like this? I was thinking of making it into an application and just clicking it whenever I need it, but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

Comment: You can not trigger with a mouse connection. Running a script via script menu, quicksilver, or an app on the dock is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer mentions `launchd`'s ability to detect and launch an app when usb devices are connected. Sounds like what you are after.

[Execute an application on Mac OS X when a particular type of USB device is connected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259762)

You can get your specific product is, to use in the plist file, from System Profile->USB

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Also KeyBoard Maestro makes this process very easy as well.